# Detect Colour in a UIImage and save CGPoints

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, core-graphics, core-image

I have a UIImage and I want all the cgPoints of the specific colour this image has. For example I have this Image

[image]

Now I want to get the RED colour CGPoints from this UIImage. Red colour may be a straight horizontal/vertical line. It may also be a curved/zigzag line.

This is what I have tried but I m unable to detect the required RED coloured CGPoints.

loop through image size/pixels to detect colour

```
var requiredPointsInImage = [CGPoint]()
    let testImage = UIImage.init(named: "imgToTest1")
    for heightIteration in 0..<Int(testImage!.size.height) {
        for widthIteration in 0..<Int(testImage!.size.width) {
            let colorOfPoints = testImage!.getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint(x:CGFloat(widthIteration), y:CGFloat(heightIteration)), withFrameSize: testImage!.size)
            if colorOfPoints == MYColor {
                print(colorOfPoints)
                requiredPointsInImage.append(CGPoint(x:CGFloat(widthIteration), y:CGFloat(heightIteration)))
            }

        }
    }

    let newImage = drawShapesOnImage(image: testImage!, points: requiredPointsInImage)
```

// Colour Detection

```
extension UIImage {
func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint, withFrameSize size: CGSize) -> UIColor {
    let x: CGFloat = (self.size.width) * pos.x / size.width
    let y: CGFloat = (self.size.height) * pos.y / size.height
    let pixelPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    let pixelData = self.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
    let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)
    let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pixelPoint.y)) + Int(pixelPoint.x)) * 3 //4

    let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
//        let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1)
}
}
```

// Drawing on detected points

```
func drawShapesOnImage(image: UIImage, points:[CGPoint]) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.setLineWidth(2.0)
    context!.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
    let radius: CGFloat = 5.0
    for point in points  {
        let center = CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y);
        context!.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: center.x,y: center.y), radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360, clockwise: true)
        context!.strokePath()
    }
    let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return resultImage!
}
```

This is what I have got .....

[image]

Note: Background may not always be white, but of course not RED.

Using the same `getPixelColor()` function I can get exact color from this below image of any CGPoint but with y constant (say y:1)

[image]

If you think there is any other better approach to detect all these points please suggest.

Comment: The pixel rows order in the raster bitmap may be in reversed order (bottom up direction). It seems your logic for accessing memory layout vs physical location of the pixels in the image is not correct.

Comment: @Kamil.S can you please explain what do you mean by "logic for accessing memory layout vs physical location of the pixels in the image"

Comment: Sure, what I mean by that is what you read in memory at let's say `heightIteration == 0` , `widthIteration == 0` is not necessarily your top left pixel corner in the raster image. The amount of pixels is correct after the whole loop, but you have a mismatch between where in memory you access and what you *think* you are reading at given `x,y`

Comment: @Kamil.S Okay, that mean `getPixelColor` function may have different cgpoints to detect color. When I m thinking it is (0,0) ...

Comment: I will check it thoroughly in the evening if you still don't have the answer. Apologies for the untested answer.

Comment: @Kamil.S no problem, yes please check if you can find any solution for me and other SO community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO I have found the solution, Actually the problem was I was ignoring Alpha channel in UIImage extension getPixelColor(). using alpha solve my problem.

here is the updated code!

```
extension UIImage {
func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint, withFrameSize size: CGSize) -> UIColor {
let x: CGFloat = (self.size.width) * pos.x / size.width
let y: CGFloat = (self.size.height) * pos.y / size.height
let pixelPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
let pixelData = self.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)
let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pixelPoint.y)) + Int(pixelPoint.x)) * 4

let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
}
}
```

And the result is:

[image]